# Session Timeout Alert message and sync the timer when user opens new window

Tags: javascript, web-applications, session-timeout

I have this requirement that a session timer be displayed on the page that keeps user informed that they would be logged out in, say 30 minutes and then this timer updates itself at each second. I have written function in javascript that does that on onLoad() function of each page I am calling this function and it works fine.

Now the problem is while just 5 mins is remaining, I need to show an alert that "you will be logged out in 5 mins" so I added a condition if(Seconds ==300) as in below code.

```
function UpdateTimer() {
        var Seconds = TotalSeconds;
        var Minutes = Math.floor(Seconds / 60);
            if(Seconds ==300)
            alert( "you will be logged out in 5 mins");
        Seconds -= Minutes * (60);
        var TimeStr =  LeadingZero(Minutes) + ":" + LeadingZero(Seconds)
        document.getElementById("digital").innerHTML = TimeStr;
}
```

Now the problem is Though an alert pops up before 5 mins of session timeout But timer could not be updated until user clicks on this alert. So in case no user action happens user session is still timed out but alert shows 5 min is remaining. And worst upon clicking alert, timer again starts counting down from 5 mins though session is already timed out.

Also take the case when user does right click and opens page in new window, then session is not timed out as user is working on new page in opened window, but my original page is not aware of this and hence it continues its countdown and shows alert before 5 mins.

Please let me  know how do I deal with this situation?

Comment: alert is BAD to use! If the user walks away, that alert stays open and there and the timer never updates. Code also would not account for action in a second browser window.

Comment: so what could be used instead of alert?

Comment: A div that is placed on the content.